# Incorrect height of an uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to put an uiview over the main view controller. The way i'm doing it, looks like this (the red view is the view, and the black one is the main view controller)
[image]

But i want it to look like this...
[image]

This is the code i have tried (the "viewww" is the red view)

```
viewww = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - navBar.frame.height))
```

What i want is to have a space in the top (the height of a navbar) and not in the bottom when the "viewww" appears, but i don't know how to set the space in the top.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This puts your view down to the height of the navBar

```
viewww = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: navBar.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - navBar.frame.height))
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked!!! Thank you so much!!! I will put your answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

The *cleanest* way to do this, without hard-coding navigation bar heights, is to use autolayout. Constrain the view's `leading` and `trailing` edges to the superview's, and constrain the view's `top` and `bottom` edges to the top layout guide and bottom layout guide (or, if you're using iOS 11, the Safe Area edges). See https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/ for a fuller explanation.